# Stuck on Mi Flash for an hour now

Tags: rom-flashing, unbricking, xiaomi

**Hi, I'm stuck on the following line in Miflash for over an hour now:**

[20:58:19 3825d80]:MiFlash 2018.5.28.0

[20:58:19 3825d80]:Thread id:12 Thread name:3825d80

[20:58:19 3825d80]:image path:D:\Downloads\root20032021\cepheus_eea_global_images_V12.0.4.0.QFAEUXM_20210115.0000.00_10.0_eea

[20:58:19 3825d80]:env android path:"D:\Downloads\root20032021\MiFlash20180528\Source\ThirdParty\Google\Android"

[20:58:19 3825d80]:script :D:\Downloads\root20032021\cepheus_eea_global_images_V12.0.4.0.QFAEUXM_20210115.0000.00_10.0_eea\flash_all.bat

[20:58:19 3825d80]:Physical Memory Usage:3317760 Byte

[20:58:19 3825d80]:start process id 4372 name cmd

[20:58:20 3825d80]:info:$set CURRENT_ANTI_VER=1

[20:58:20 3825d80]:info:$for /F "tokens=2 delims=: " %i in ('fastboot -s 3825d80 getvar anti 2>&1 | findstr /r /c:"anti:"') do (set version=%i )

**Is it safe to unplug the device and try again?**

Comment: the script hangs on reading info via fastboot. is the rabbit on your phone?